# Does Apache Hive support semi structured or unstructured data?

Tags: hive

Can Apache Hive store Image/video files?

or XML, JSON?

> For example I have a video file and I need it in Hive.
>
> Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Sort of.

Hive requires you to specify schema up front, but it has complex types and a binary type, and you can plug in custom SerDes and Input/Output formats.

As an example, I could imagine a custom SerDe that reads images or video and outputs metadata columns like size and encoding format, plus a "raw data" binary column.

As for JSON and XML, there are preexisting SerDes for those that will access specific configurable fields. Again, you have to define these fields up front, but the actual data can certainly be in JSON or XML on disk.

Comment: If Image/video files are in binary format, is it possible to store it in Hive? If so, How can you do that and will I be able to query it or just simply store it?